# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Tags: php

I'm trying to save an id number in my database and I can't seem to store an integer inside the `$resultid` variable.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['tittel'])) {

    $meny = $_POST['meny'];
    $tittel = $_POST['tittel'];
    $innhold = $_POST['innhold'];
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'vikerfjell');
    if ($con) {
        echo "Connected!";
        "<br>";
    } else {
        die("Connection failed!");
    }

    $menyid = ("SELECT idmeny FROM meny WHERE tekst = '$meny'");
    $resultid = mysqli_query($con, $menyid);
    $resultarr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultid);

    $query = "INSERT INTO innhold (tittel, tekst, idmeny) ";
    $query. = "VALUES('$tittel', '$innhold', $resultarr)";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    "<br>";

    if (!$result) {
        die('Query FAILED!'.mysqli_error($con));
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot put `$resultarr` in the next query like you do. You probably have to use something like `$resultarr[0]['idmeny']`.

Comment: Guessing `$resultarr` holds multiple `idmeny`, so you really have to loop through each `$resultarr` array and create multiple insert statements

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_fetch_assoc- fetch a result row as an associative array, u need to select the key of the id u are tying to store

```
  $menyid  = ("SELECT idmeny FROM meny WHERE tekst = '$meny'");
  $resultid = mysqli_query($con, $menyid);
  $resultarr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultid);

  $column_id=$resultarr['id_stored_on_db'];


  $query = "INSERT INTO innhold (tittel, tekst, idmeny) ";
  $query .="VALUES('$tittel', '$innhold', $column_id)";
```

Comment: Now I get this error. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`vikerfjell`.`innhold`, CONSTRAINT `idmenyFK` FOREIGN KEY (`idmeny`) REFERENCES `meny` (`idmeny`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Answer (score 0):

Guessing `$resultarr` holds multiple `idmeny`, so you really have to loop through each `idmeny` and create multiple insert statements, as such:

```
$menyid = "SELECT idmeny FROM meny WHERE tekst = '$meny'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $menyid);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO innhold (tittel, tekst, idmeny) ";
    $query .= "VALUES('$tittel', '$innhold', {$row['idmeny']})";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
}
```

Comment: But I only want one id number. The variable $meny is a dropdown box that holds the text from a table in my database. I want the id number that corresponds to that text.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I missed a value in my dropdown code (another php file). Thanks anyway : )